# Where clause in Laravel 4 query

Tags: php, laravel-4

May be is something very easy but as I'm really new in Laravel and MVC frameworks can't figured it out.

Currently the source which I have showing products on the home page. Now I want to put `WHERE` clause in the query ... but I can't find the query.. What I have in `HomeController.php` is

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::paginate(15);
    return View::make('site.index', [
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}
```

In the `models/Product.php` this

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Where exactly I should put `WHERE cat_id = 1`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write,

```
$products = Product::where('cat_id','=','1')->paginate(15);
```

Please refer [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination) also.

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: I'm glad I've helped you :)